# Put combinations of symbols, so the result will have the same numbers of As, Bs and Cs

Tags: combinatorics

Put combinations of symbols A, AA, AAB, AABB, AABC, AAC, ABB, ABC, AC, B, BB, BC, and C to each circle, in such a way that the symbols in each row with 3 or 4 circles in all three directions, have the same numbers of A,B, and C.

[image]

Comment: Jamal, is the diagonal row containing both the given 'ABB' and 'B' combinations possible to solve? There are 3 'B's in that row, so at minimum we need three 'C's. However, no combination has multiple 'C's, so we can only have a maximum of two 'C's in that diagonal, making it impossible to solve.

Comment: I believe the numbers of A,B and C in each row dont have to match, but the number has to be the same for every row. E.g. The diagonal can have 2XA,3XB, 2XC. Then all rows should have the same amount of each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solved "grid" looks like this:

> [image]

Solve path:

> There are a total of 14A, 11B and 6C. This leaves the only possibility of 4A, 3B and 2C in each row. This gives us the placement of the A and AAB. The other two corners need 2A and 2B in total, the only possibility is AA and BB and the first horizontal row shows us how to place them. Starting at the row between BB and AAB will then fill in the rest.